# Korean dialogue in a comic

Tags: korean-to-english, korean-culture

I'm brazilian, and reading a comic in english. It's named "Shortcomings", by Adrian Tomine. This comic is about problems of some asian-american young adults. At some point, the main character (Ben Tanaka, from japanese ascendence) goes to a wedding with his korean friend (Alice) pretending to be her boyfriend. She don't want their parents to discover that she is homossexual, so she brings her friend with her as her boyfriend.

One of the problems is: He is not korean, he have japanese ascendence, and, for historical and cultural reasons, Alice advises him that probably her parents will not like him.

When Alice presents him to her parents, they talk in korean with each other, and she replies something to them.

I could not find a translation, and automatic translators could not give me a reasonable translation.

Can someone tell me what are they talking? They're probably discussing about Ben's japanese descent.

Thank you all in advance.

[image: Part of the comic "Shortcomings" by Adrian Tomine]

Comment: By the way, I appreciate the awesome amount of context you provided. They are really helpful for answering questions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my translation. It doesn't feel as smooth as the original Korean version, but might be enough to get you a rough sense:

> - 그 남자가 일본인이란 말이야?
> - 딱 보면 알지. 왜 몰라?

- So is he a Japanese?
- I know, right?

> - 이런 뒷담은 안 하면 안 될까?
> - 왜, 그런 거 물어보면 안 되는 거냐?

- Can't we just not talk like this(behind his back)?
- What's the deal? We can ask about it?

> - 한국인이면 그냥 대놓고 애기하지. *(Note: `애기하지` here seems to be a misspelled of `얘기하지`.)*
> - 아이고... 혹시나 했더니 역시나... 창피해 더이상 못 참겠다!

- We would've said it directly if he were Korean.
- Oh, my, this is embarrassing. You never disappoint me, do you? I can't stand it anymore!

(The conversation is in a very casual tone, which makes it hard to be translated in English.)